# Personal "a" expressed in object pronoun

Tags: persona-gramatical

Something I learn in my highschool course: whenever a verb proceeds a person immediately, we have to separate them with a "a".

One day, I went ask my teacher which object pronoun do I replace "a someone" with. And she said direct object pronoun.

Today, something I read made me doubt about what she told me.

> Si la abeja le pica le va a salir una roncha. (If a bee stings you (Ud form), it will leave you a welt)

**actually I am not even sure if I translated it right.**

Comment: [Here](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg) is a lot of information about using "a + direct object"

Comment: Additionally: the example you read is correct, as well as your translation. *Le* can sometimes be used as direct object pronoun, instead of *lo* (which is always correct).

Comment: @Gorpik, so when can "le" be used in place of "lo"? I have always been taught that only "lo" is direct.

Comment: The full explanation is a bit long, but *le* can be used instead of *lo* in many cases when the direct object is a male person (or persons). This is more usual in Spain than in other Spanish-speaking countries.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion likely comes from three facts:

1. When used with redundant pronoun, indirect objects must necessarily be introduced with *a* (*para* rejects redundant pronouns).
2. When a direct object is a animate (that is, a person or otheranthropomorphized being), it must necessarily be precedeed with the preposition *a*.
3. The direct object pronoun may be either *lo* (most common) or *le* (animate male or usted, depending on region)

If you were to say that a bee stung John, you'd say:

> Una abeja picó a José.

This makes us think initially that *picar* is a verb that takes indirect objects which would cause us to think we'd need *le*.  There are two ways to prove that *María* is not an indirect object:

> *Una abeja picó **para** José.
>   *Una abeja picó **al** globo.

Neither sentence works (and hence I've preceeded them with an asterisk, which means "not grammatical").

Now, given that we know it's a direct object, you'd expect us be able to write

> Una abeja **lo** picó (a José).
>   Una abeja **la** picó (a María).

And this is in fact the most common way you would hear this in Spanish and probably what you're expecting after being told it's a direct object, but perhaps conflicting a bit with the fact that we've introduced José with *a*, which makes you think that *le* would be more acceptable.

But actually, in some regions, for people (like José), you can use *le* as a masculine animate direct object and so the following would be acceptable:

> Una abeja **le** picó (a José).
>   Una abeja **la** picó (a María).
>   Una abeja **le** picó (a Vd. quien se llama José)
>   Una abeja **la** picó (a Vd. quien se llama María)

In other regions in you can't do it for José as 3rd person, but you can do it for either José *or* María directly as *usted* (called the *leísmo de cortesía*)

> Una abeja **lo** picó (a José).
>   Una abeja **la** picó (a María).
>   Una abeja **le** picó (a Vd. quien se llama José)
>   Una abeja **le** picó (a Vd. quien se llama María)

Some regions even combine both types:

> Una abeja **le** picó (a José).
>   Una abeja **la** picó (a María).
>   Una abeja **le** picó (a Vd. quien se llama José)
>   Una abeja **le** picó (a Vd. quien se llama María)

In no region can you use *le* for anything that's not a person (or similar, like a pet), regardless of gender, number, or person.

So ultimately... in your example of "si una abeja le pica…", depending on region, the *le* could ultimately be heard as ungrammatical, or as meaning *him/you sir*, or as meaning *you sir/you ma'am*, or as meaning *him/you sir/you ma'am*.  Since you intend it to mean *usted*, *le* works fine — so long as you're in a region that accepts the *leísmo de cortesía*  (which is actually larger than the region that accepts the *leísmo* for masculine animates, so most people will understand you fine in addition to it being accepted by the RAE as correct)

Answer (score 1):

The personal `a` is meant most of the time for emphasis.

Your sentence lacks the emphasis

> Si una abeja le pica **a usted** le va a salir una roncha

Comment: Emphasis on what?

Comment: `A mi me gustan los tacos` vs `Me gustan los tacos`.. The first one is more clear and emphasized.

Comment: Veo una mesa.  Veo a una niña.  No emphasis!  I think it's the presence of the object pronoun itself that creates the emphasis.  I think the personal *a* just indicates personhood.